# I want to check values in two columns at same index should not occur in rows of a group dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I have two tables:
df_exclude having products that should not come together to the same customer i.e product1 and product2 at 0 index should not be given to the same customer:

| product1 | product2 |
| --- | --- |
| 565043 | 5649965 |
| 5649585 | 5649910 |
| 5649585 | 5649921 |
| 5649607 | 5649931 |
| 5649607 | 5649929 |

df_customers:

| customers | product | relevancy_score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A10001 | 5650743 | 0.646916 |
| A10001 | 5649965 | 0.608653 |
| A10001 | 5649679 | 0.587336 |
| A10001 | 5650455 | 0.581182 |
| A10001 | 5650462 | 0.575269 |
| A10787 | 5650544 | 0.008170 |
| A10787 | 5649815 | 0.003877 |
| A10787 | 5649925 | 0.002392 |
| A10787 | 5649963 | 0.002319 |
| A10787 | 5649836 | 0.002269 |

i.e customer A10001 should get only one of the products, not both of products at same index for example  customer A10001 should either get 565043   or 5649965    but can't get both of them . But we can see in the df_customers table that he have got both the product so I have to remove the row having product 5649965 with the A10001 customer. How can I solve this with python.

Comment: How is df_customers related to df_exclude. In your example for A10001 there is no  entry for product 5649646 so results already look fine . To me its not clear what is input and what is output.

Comment: please provide a code snippet to regenerate the dataframe.

Comment: If you find a customer that has both, what do you want to do? In your example, if A10001 had two records `5649565` and `5649646` then what should happen to df_customers dataframe

Comment: Can you please re go through the tables I have changed the values to explain what i want

Answer (score 0):

by taking similar case here is what i did

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'product1':[1277,3921,1277,3921],'product2':[1854,2561,9132,5143]})
    product1    product2
0   1277    1854
1   3921    2561
2   1277    9132
3   3921    5143



df2=pd.DataFrame({'customer':['a1','a1','a1','a2','a2','a2'],'products':[1277,1854,9132,1277,1853,9332,]})
    customer    products
0   a1  1277
1   a1  1854
2   a1  9132
3   a2  1277
4   a2  1853
5   a2  9332




def fun(h):
  return list(h)

df2=df2.groupby('customer').agg(fun)
```

df2 after groupby

```
           products
customer    
a1  [1277, 1854, 9132]
a2  [1277, 1853, 9332]


validcustomer=[]
for x in range(len(df2)):
  temp=df2.iloc[x].products
  c=0
  for y in range(len(df)):
    if df.iloc[y].product1 in temp and df.iloc[y].product2 in temp:
      c=1
      validcustomer.append(False)
      break
  if c==0:
    validcustomer.append(True)
df2["validity"]=validcustomer
```

df2 after this

```
         products   validity
customer        
a1  [1277, 1854, 9132]  False
a2  [1277, 1853, 9332]  True
```

what i did was complete brute force very efficient codes can also be written.
i might have been easy if you have explained your problem better and given dome code to regenerate the dataframe.

Comment: actually in the sample data that you have created 1277, 1854 is in the the list of products of customer a1. And the table df shows that at 0th index product1 is 1277 and product 2 is 1854, that means if a customer have 1277 in his product list he should not have 1854. so we have to remove the row with product 1854.